# Mocha `retries` callback argument doesn't compile in typescript

Tags: typescript, mocha.js, webdriver-io

Below code will not compile in ts but works very well in es2015

```
it('should do stuff', () => {
    expect(HomePage.title.getText()).to.be.eq('Google');
}, 3); // retries 3 times, works in ES6 but doesn't even compile in typescript
```

**Error message:** [ts] expected 1-2 arguments, but got 3.

It will compile after removing `, 3`, how can I make the IDE understand the retry callback in ts? Is it a problem with tsconfig? I'm using VS Code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can I make the IDE understand the retry callback in ts

The docs doesn't show this argument : https://mochajs.org/#retry-tests

## Fix

- The code is invalid and TypeScript is pointing it out.
- Follow the docs for the correct code i.e. use `this.retries`

Comment: Tried that too, it did not compile either. Error: x Unable to compile Typescript. `this` implicitly has type `any` because it does not have a type annotation.

Comment: nvm, with a close look, Mocha doesn't like lamdas. Changed to `function()` and works. https://mochajs.org/#arrow-functions Thank you!